# Relation between zero resistance and diamagnetism

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, superconductivity, bose-einstein-condensate

Can zero resistance and perfect diamagnetism in a [type-1 superconductor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-I_superconductor) be related somehow? Because we know that having infinite conductivity alone doesn't decide the material to be a superconductor